# Autload .env values in vscode (windows11)

Tags: visual-studio-code, environment-variables, windows-11, .env

For some weird reasons, I bought a windows laptop and now i am struggling with so many tiny things. For example, my app has `.env` and `.env.production` file which contains env variables. i remember that there was some env utility which can see if there is .env file in a directory and if so, it loads all values.

is there something similar for windows11 and vscode? or whats the best way to load all of these values?

Comment: i would propose: 1.use a script [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72001469/592355) 2. `code .` from that same shell/script

Comment: but there are also 2 extensions look-/reading promising, but the [one not documented](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BernardXiong.env-vscode), the [other in chinese](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yq612.env-control) ;(

Comment: Do you actually need those environment variables to be in the environment for the VS Code processes? Or do you only needed them for child processes such as VS Code tasks and programs you debug using launch configurations?

Comment: ^^ i am supposed to use `npm run build` to start my app. i am doing it from vs code terminal. i think what you are hinting that i should create launch configuration and put thos variables there?